# how to activate digital goods on paypal Mexico

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

When I use  digital goods (express checkout) on sandbox, everything runs ok, but when I try to use under production gives this error:

> "You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered
>   goods.".

on my panel paypal don't find that configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign up for the digital goods at below link :

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/digital-goods

In case in doesn't work you need to contact the PayPal support to enable it on your account .

Comment: thank you, the link, that you give me, says: "Pagina no encontrada", do you think it works on Paypal Mexico?

Comment: If that doesn't work for you , I will advise you to contact the PayPal Support to enable it on your account ( if its available).