# how to enable digital goods checkout in paypal express checkout?

Tags: paypal

i want to enable digital goods checkout in PayPal express checkout, how to enable that? PayPal is saying it is not available for new implementations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29781525/6369494

Answer (score 0):

As per the Paypal Link here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/

> **Enabling your PayPal Account for Digital Goods**
>
> Please contact your sales representative to enable your account for
>   PayPal Digital Goods. Additionally, merchants in the US or Canada can
>   contact either 1-855-477-5673 or 1-888-818-3922 to activate Digital
>   Goods for their accounts.
>   Blockquote

Also sharing screenshot
https://www.screencast.com/t/3saWI7qg

After You enabled Paypal For Digital Goods 
You can use Demo created by us

Working Demo is here http://paypalphp-sandbox.angelleye.com/

Comment: PayPal can enable this setting in 10 minutes so don't wait over a week like I did.